# Syntax error in simple program

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to program something but there's some kind of syntax error which I can't work out. Any help would be much appreciated. Here's my code:

```
begin
  puts"Enter a number to count, or to exit type 0."
  y = gets.chomp.to_i
  if y == 0
    exit
  end
  puts"Now put the number you're starting with"
  x = gets.chomp.to_i
  if y + x == 12 or y + x < 12
    print x + y
  end
  if y + x > 12
    n = y + x - 12
  end
  begin
    if n < 12 or n == 12
      print n
    end
    if n > 12
      n = n - 12
    end
  end until if n < 12 or n == 12
end until y == 0
end
```

Comment: I can see infinite loop

Comment: That may be the next step. But syntax error should be solved before that.

Comment: Do have any ideas of how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `until if` if wrong. They are each control sequences. You shouldn't need both.

Answer (score 0):

Your `n` is not visible later in the code. Declare `n=0` for example before `if y + x > 12` to make it visible and accessible in the relevant code blocks.

Then, `until if` is wrong, this should simply be `until`

Lastly, delete the last `end` keyword.